# Unable to validate htaccess regex

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect URLs with .htaccess in order to be able to make this:

request: `http://www.example.org/business/businesswhatever/`

redirect: `http://www.example.org/businessgrowing/businesswhatever/`

The more close I am of reaching the solution is to apply this code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)example\.org/businessgrow/(.*)$ $example.org/businessgrowing/$2 [R=301,L]
```

but it does not work at all. Validator doesn't check a thing, the only way to validate is if I omit http:// part of the URL.
I need to use hostname as part of the regex because some changes were made and now businessgrow is inside this path: www.example.org/corp/businessgrow, so I need to take part of the hostname in the regex in order to distingish between example.org/businessgrow (it must be a 404) and example.org/corp/businessgrow (200 OK)

I'm using this checker http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ in order to test before deploying the solution. I tried to remove a slash from http:// (because I was unable to think anything else, I already tried anything) and it worked, but validator (I mean, it doesn't skip validation) outputs 3 slashes like this `http:///www.example.org/en/businessgrow/businesswhatever/`
If I input the URL without http:// code above works perfectly, but Apache doesn't recognise it and website is unable to show a single page.
I'm using Debian wheezy server and I'm using Wordpress, i took care of write this line just below REwriteBase line, so my .htacces is like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)example\.org/businessgrow/(.*)$ $1example.org/businessgrowing/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I would appreciate if anybody gives me a clue in order to solve this, I think there's some mistake with validation process but I can't find it.
Thanks so much for your time!

btw, sorry about my english..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want the hostname as part of the regex, only the request URI path is used to match. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^businessgrow/(.*)$ /businessgrowing/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The thing is I need to use the hostname as a part of the regex, because some changes were made in order to have /businessgrow inside hostname/corp/businessgrow

Comment: @Hmorv But after all its only one htaccess which is being used for one domain?

Comment: yes, just one htaccess and only used for one domain

Comment: @Hmorv if you *must* match against the hostname, then use a condition (see edit)

Comment: wow, it worked great! thanks so much. I don't know why it fails if I use only RewriteRule instead a condition